# How do I read files on a share

Tags: java, file

We need to read a file on a share. This is for a Java app so it could be running on an iSeries and hitting a linux share (so different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680603/how-do-i-crud-files-findall-on-a-share) - and I think much harder).

And the share could be on our domain, another domain, or a local share (permission granted only to local users on that machine).

This is all for \\server\share access.

As to why such an all-encompassing need, this is for a commercial library we ship. I have no idea what our customers will face and so I want to try and cover any possibility.

Comment: If I understand your question, the problem is mostly related to the operating system.  The shared drive has to be mounted on the machine the java program runs.  As long as this is done, you should be able to access the file by supplying its full path name (including the \\server\share part).  There are a few caveats, for example, in linux, if you use the file manager to access a shared drive, sometimes you do not get a mount point.

Comment: @SciProg - Yes. But we need to handle the cases where reading the file requires authentication/authorization. For example, the payroll app reading employee salaries in an XML file on a server that needs authorized credentials to read that file.

Comment: This question lacks essential information. What do you mean by 'a share'? That phrase could mean any number of things depending on the operating systems and network protocols in use. Are we talking CIFS? NFS? You seem to be concerned about reading across the network without help from the local operating system at all. That's an extremely broad question.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/509627/david-thielen As stated before, the answer depends on which OS the java program runs.  For example, on linux (you mentionned iSeries?), my first choice would be to mount the shared drive before running the java program (search 'mounting files in linux' or have a look at 'linux fstab' for how to do it automatically).  Another way (definitely NOT my first choice!) would be to call a batch file using a java ProcessBuilder.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hesitate to try to answer this, but here goes.

Your question seems to address two distinctive situations.

In situation #1, the local system has mounted a remote file system using some remote file system protocol. In this case, the files are accessible from Java like all other files, and there is no special authentication or authorization to worry about.

In situation #2, you are allowing the user to give you some custom pathname syntax that names a resource on a remote system, where that resource is not mounted on the local operating system, and you want to read from it.

That is a very broad and large job. There is no general Java facility that addresses this at all. For example, if the you want to access a remote Windows file system via CIFS, you might try https://jcifs.samba.org/, but it hasn't been updated since 2014. If you need to access files on a Linux system via NFS, you could look at http://j-ftp.sourceforge.net/, but that looks quite rough. Or you could work with SSH, for which there are several Java client libraries to choose from.

Or, you could write native code to use the Windows API to do the work (Win32 does have ways and means of at least accessing a CIFS resource that was not previously mounted with 'net use'), and then write JNI code to get to the native code.

Comment: I think you gave a good answer which is - it depends. There is no single way to access remote files and it's very dependent on the O/S you're on on the remote file system. Not what I wanted to hear but "you can't do it" is good to know rather than spending tons of hours trying to find a way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open files on a share.  My experience is when the file constructor is successful and a stream is also successfully created you can read the file.